# How do I make a connection to a DB2 database in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, db2

I am trying to connect with Python to an AS/400 system which uses DB2. The piece of code that I actually have is:

```
from ibm_db import connect

connection = connect('DATABASE=<DB>;'
                     'HOSTNAME=<HOST_IP>;'
                     'PORT=<PORT>;'
                     'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;'
                     'UID=<USER>;'
                     'PWD=<PASSOWRD>;', '', '')
```

All of this with my information.

But when I try to make the connection, I get this error from Python terminal:

```
Exception: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "<IP>".  Communication func SQLCODE=-30081the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001
```

I've checked in the AS/400 that the port was listening with the "netstat" command.

The IBM documentation is less than helpful in this, anyone knows any possible solution?

Comment: For clidriver, you need an additional license file to access i-series (which you get from your Db2-connect contact)   Otherwise, if you don't want that, then you need to use a different driver, from the "IBM i access" product which has an odbc option.  This is a FAQ.  Then you need to verify the IP-address and port-number and databasename, and verify that no firewall prevents traffic between the hostname running python, and the as400.

Comment: How can I get that license file and where do I need to put it? I'm kinda new in this IBM world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most efficient way to connect to a db2 database is by ODBC.

If you are working under windows,first you should create a new odbc connnection under "User DSN" tab ( i.e `"AS400"`)

[image]

Then, you can connect to it:

```
import pyodbc 
conn_db2 = pyodbc.connect('DSN=AS400; UID=my_id; PWD=my_password')
```

To fetch a table, you can use:

```
import pandas as pd
query = f'''SELECT * FROM mytable'''
table = pd.read_sql(query, conn_db2)
conn_sql.close()
```